# Bitbucket rest api to compare two branches

Tags: bitbucket-api

Doing some automation for our dev team and wanted to know if its possible to find the difference between two branches in bitbucket using the rest API.
I know there is a rest endpoint for diff but I am not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends on whether you are using Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server as those are two separate products and have separate APIs.

For Bitbucket Cloud I believe you can use something like this:

```
 https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/get/ruby-pg/commits/stable?exclude=stable&fields=values.message,next
```

For more information refer to this [community page](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Cloud-REST-API-to-list-all-commit-messages-between-two/qaq-p/676759). Note that I have not tested the API myself.

As for Bitbucket Server, I have yet to find an equivalent. If anyone finds out please share!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you want to compare.
Maybe you can try this:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/WORKSPACENAME/REPONAME/commits/?include=dev&exclude=main
```

This API call can compare the different commit between branch **dev** and **main**